# Scripting disabled on Powershell script called from Makefile

Tags: powershell, makefile

I have a Makefile that has the following code:

```
SHELL := powershell.exe
.SHELLFLAGS := -NoProfile -Command 

# Save the virtual environment path for later use
VENV_PATH = $(shell poetry env info --path)

# Activate the virtual environment
activate:
    & $(VENV_PATH)\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

However, whenever I call `make activate` from Powershell, I get the following error:

> & : File .venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
> scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

However, when I do `Get-ExecutionPolicy` I see that it shows "Unrestricted" so I'm not sure what's going on here.